# Printing a file from server

Tags: command-line, printing

Is it possible to print a file from my schools server terminal to my printer.  How would i do that?  Im not sure if this is possible if not how would i view the printers that are set up to print files.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually quite easy to print from a terminal, if you have a printer configured as a `/dev/lp` device.

You can quite simply:

```
cat somefile.ps > /dev/lp
```

or

```
cat morestuff.txt | lpr
```

You can read all about printing from the command line [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Printing-Usage-HOWTO-2.html).